# Create a Custom Variable in Nagios

Tags: c, variables, nagios

I created a variable in define host {} like this :

```
      define host {
                    [...]
                    _type       box

      }
```

I modified in C files to use this variable for a specific reason, but during installation this error appears :

[image]

Can you please help me to find a solution for using this variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use custom host variables as they're intended? Here's a link to the documentation https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/customobjectvars.html

Don't mess with the code - this can have a lot of unintended consequences. A LOT of other code you aren't considering depends on the structures of these types.

But here is an example host definition with a custom variable:

```
define host {
  host_name     this_host
  _type         SOME DATA YOU WANT
  check_command some_check!$HOST_TYPE$!
}
```